# When Non-Constant Analytic Functions are Real-Unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a real analytic function which is non-constant.  Are there simple conditions on $f$ to deduce that
$$
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \|f(x)\|=\infty
?
$$

*Thoughts:*
From the analyticity alone, I can deduce that it is not compactly supported.  However, that doesn't seem to be enough to guarantee that it is bounded in norm; i.e. consider $x\mapsto \exp(-x^2)$.

In constrast, it seems that all non-constant polynomial do satisfy this condition.  So, the class of functions $\mathcal{X}$ which I'm interested in lyies somewhere between
$$
\left\{f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m:\mbox{non-constant polynomial}\right\} \subseteq \mathcal{X} \subset \left\{f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m:\, \mbox{f is analytic}\right\}.
$$

Is a characterization of $\mathcal{X}$ known?

Comment: even in the simplest case where $n=1$ and the function extends to an entire function in the complex plane it is very hard to come up with such conditions (essentially that the function is unbounded on lines); the only "general" condition is that in this case, any counterexample - any entire function bounded on the reals or on some other line - needs to have order at least $1$ as by Phrgamen-Lindelof it is not hard to show that an entire function of order strictly less than one must be unbounded on every line, including the real one

Comment: What do you mean by order?  I'm not familiar with this concept

Comment: it is the order of growth of an entire function; see the Wikipedia article for details and examples; essentially the higher the order, the less uniform the function can grow, so in particular in infinite order, one can have entire functions bounded on any line through the origin (the function being highly unbounded of course), in finite high order we can have same on lots of lines, etc until in order less than 1 (polynomials have order zero of course and grow fairly uniformly in all directions) that cannot happen; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function